# jinja2 + reStructured Markup

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, restructuredtext

The idea is the following. I send some text to jinja2 using tags similar to stackoverflow's. How do I tell jinja2 to treat them as a markup containing text and to generate bold, italic and so on text in html?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
from docutils.core import publish_string
import jinja2

html = publish_string(source=text, writer_name='html')
node = jinja2.Markup(html)
```

Where `node` is the Jinja 2 node to actually include in your scope.

Comment: What should I do if I need only the html syntax part ? I can put that .css style away in another file.

Comment: @DTailor: you could use parts of the html: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/api/publisher.html#parts-provided-by-the-html-writer

Answer (score 5):

I'm used to [django-markdown](http://freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Django), so I think using a filter is a nice way to accomplish this:

```
   <div class="content">{{ article.body|rst }}</div>
```

I'm not aware if such filter exists for jinja2 but [it should be very easy to write](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters). I guess something in the line of this (untested code):

```
from docutils.core import publish_parts
import jinja2

def rst_filter(s):
    return jinja2.Markup(publish_parts(source=s, writer_name='html')['body'])
environment.filters['rst'] = rst_filter
```

Comment: This works... but for filter, instead of publish_string() is better to use publish_parts()['html_body']. Thanks!

Comment: @AdiRoiban: I believe you and want to update my answer to reflect your suggestion, but would you mind to explain the reason why publish_parts is better than publish_string? TIA.

Comment: This comment system is ugly... how do I add code?

publish_string with "html" writer will create a _whole_ HTML document, including head, styleguides and body.

Try this:

```
from docutils.core import publish_string, publish_parts

publish_string(source='rst', writer_name='html')

publish_parts(source='rst', writer_name='html')['body']
```

Comment: @AdiRoiban: thanks for the explanation! for including code snippets in the comment system, I like to publish them in [gist](http://gist.github.com) and post the link here.